# Show the convergence of a sequence of integrals to a given integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, laplace-method

I would like to show that :

$$\int_{0}^1(3t^2 -2t^3)^n \mathrm{d}t \underset{n \rightarrow+\infty}{\sim} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-3x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

I thought of showing the equivalent result:

$$\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^1(3t^2 -2t^3)^n \mathrm{d}t \underset{n \rightarrow+\infty}{\longrightarrow}  \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-3x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

I tried using the binomial expansion and that for all $x\in\mathbb{R},$ $e^{-3x^2} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-3x^2)^k}{k!}$, I also thought of changing the bounds of the integrals. But I don't really know yet how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited based on comment by Travor Liu*

This is going to be a bit messy, and I'm not going to be super precise with justifying why everything works, but we're essentially going to use [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) for integral asymptotics.

We begin with rewriting the integral as follows:
$$\int_{0}^1(3t^2 -2t^3)^n \, dt = \int_{0}^{1}e^{n\ln(3t^{2} - 2t^{3})}\,dt,$$ and we note that $\ln(3t^2 - 2t^3) < 0$ on $(0,1)$, and that as $n\to \infty$ the area on $(0,\varepsilon)$, for $\varepsilon > 0$ becomes negligible.  With that in mind, we expand $\ln(3t^{2} - 2t^{3})$ around $t = 1$ (via Taylor series) to get $$\ln(3t^{2} - 2t^{3}) = -3(t-1)^{2} + O((t-1)^3),$$ and so $$\int_{0}^{1}e^{n\ln(3t^{2} - 2t^{3})}\,dt \sim \int_{0}^{1}e^{-3n(t-1)^{2}}\,dt, \quad\text{as }n\to\infty.$$  Now, we do a change of variables
\begin{align}
u &= 3n(t-1)^2 \implies t- 1 = \pm\sqrt{\frac{u}{3n}}\\
du &= 6n(t-1)\,dt = -6n\sqrt{\frac{u}{3n}}\,dt = -2\sqrt{3n}\sqrt{u}\,dt.
\end{align}
Note that, as we will see momentarily, we choose the negative root so that the integral remains positive.  With this substitution, we get
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}e^{-3n(t-1)^{2}}\,dt = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3n}}\int_{3n}^{0}u^{-1/2}e^{-u}\,du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3n}}\int_{0}^{3n}u^{-1/2}e^{-u}\,du.
\end{align}
Now, the because we have the factor of $e^{-u}$, the integrand becomes exponentially small as $u\to \infty$, and so we only introduce exponentially small error by extending the upper limit of the integral to infinity.  This gives us
$$
\int_{0}^1(3t^2 -2t^3)^n \, dt \sim \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3n}}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-1/2}e^{-u}\,du\quad\text{as }n\to\infty.$$

At this point we make us of the change of variables $u = 3x^2$, which gives us

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3n}}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-1/2}e^{-u}\,du =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3n}}\int_0^\infty(3x^2)^{-1/2}e^{-3x^2}(6x)\,dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-3x^2}\, dx.$$

So, we obtain

$$\boxed{\int_{0}^1(3t^2 -2t^3)^n \, dt\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-3x^2}\, dx\quad\text{as }n\to\infty}$$

Now, if we wanted to be a bit more precise, we could write
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3n}}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-1/2}e^{-u}\,du&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3n}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}},
\end{align}
where here $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), and so in reality we have
$$\int_{0}^1(3t^2 -2t^3)^n \, dt\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}},\qquad\text{as }n\to\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you. But can it be done without calculating directly the first integral?

Comment: @Axel - I've had time to come back to this and I've updated my answer with a (mostly) full solution.  There are some fine details to resolve, but the main pieces are all there.

Comment: We do not have to know the actual value of the integral on the RHS because if we were to set $u=3x^2$ we have $${1\over\sqrt{3n}}\int_0^\infty u^{-1/2}e^{-u}\mathrm du={1\over2\sqrt{3n}}\int_0^\infty(3x^2)^{-1/2}e^{-3x^2}(6x)\mathrm dx={1\over\sqrt n}\int_0^\infty e^{-3x^2}\mathrm dx$$

Comment: @TravorLiu - I decided I liked your approach, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @DMcMor I found a more rigourous way to prove the result. Should I post it?

Comment: Up to you, go ahead if you think it would be useful.